# Typescript not triggering errors for an uninitialized object property named "name"

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, compiler-errors, typescript-typings

I've found some weird behavior on a Typescript code that I'm writing.

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDkAqBRASgMQEEBhbAfUOQG8AoZe5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwA0NAL40aMAK4gEYYAHsQyGHLmEAFAA8OGHARLlCASm1Y8RUhWrIoEMBKiKNAbmSjxK9bQaMWKb-4DA5AB6YORMAAlUAGVkaIiAeQBVABkAEWQAIWxkQnRkPFwE3GQ1TKTMNEwAclj0BMxDEUMnMQQFbmQ5ACMAK0ITXXMDZABeajoGJlYg2cDQ8KjY+OT0rJy8gtwikrKKqtrkesaRMVBIWEQUHTN9MkyJ7wA3OAAbCXYuHn5T8SkZeSKZRyTKaQa3CyZYxoUx6SFWGx2BzIZyuMTA0FeBgvd5+Ob4haRGJoWKbQrFUoJADSTWELTaHTAXT6mXBcPID3GWPoOI++P5hKWJNy+XJu2ptLEQA)

Somehow Typescript does not trigger an error for an not initialized property if that property name is `name` :

[image]

What is this? Is this a bug or what?

This is the error for the `value` property:

> No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'value'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.(18004)

[image]

```
interface INTERFACE_A {
    name: string,               // ALSO TRIED WITH OTHER TYPES. SAME RESULT
}

function fooA(x: INTERFACE_A): INTERFACE_A { return x; }

fooA({
    name                        // THIS SHOULD BE AN ERROR (BUT IT'S NOT)
});

const objA: INTERFACE_A = {
    name                        // THIS SHOULD BE AN ERROR (BUT IT'S NOT)
}

interface INTERFACE_B {
    value: string
}

function fooB(x: INTERFACE_B): INTERFACE_B { return x; }

fooB({
    value                       // THIS IS AN ERROR (OK)
});

const objB: INTERFACE_B = {
    value                       // THIS IS AN ERROR (OK)
}
```

This doesn't seem to be related to the Typescript Playground, since it's also happening in my VSCode dev environment:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

This is probably related to the `window.name` property, which is of type `string`. But it still behaves differently than `window.innerWidth`, for example:

See that TS complains if I use `innerWidth` as a `string`, but it does not complain when I try to use `window.name` as a `number`:

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDkAqBRASgMQEEBhbAfUOQG8AoZe5EOAWwgC5GBXZgI2gBoaAXxo0YnEAjDAA9iGQwZMwgAoAHhww4CJcoQCUmrHiKkK1ZFAhhOUeWoDcyEWKWraDRixSfff-8gA9IHImAASqADKyJFhAPIAqgAyACLIAELYyIToyHi4cbjIKukJmGiYAOTR6HGY+sL6DqIIcgDOYMgyPABWhEbapnrIALzUdAxMrAEz-sGhEdGxiakZWTl5uAVFJWUV1ci19cKioJCwiChaJrpk6eOeoCDQAOrAACZgABYcHVCgAHMTmIJFJZPJFDJ0uoBjczOlDGhjDp4RYrDY7MhHM5RJDoR4GE9Xh9vrMyfR5uEomhoht8oVinEANINIRNFrtTrdHrpWEo8j3MYE+hEqBvT5fclkymLGnZXL0nbM1miIA)

[image]

[image]

Comment: @arslan2012 I've added the playground just as an example. But this is also happening in my local DEV environment on VSCode. I don't think it's related to the playground.

Answer (score 1):

`{ name }` is shorthand for `{ name: name }`, `window.name` is built-in property, and properties of `window` are global in browsers, so `name` is a global property that's equivalent to `window.name`.

In effect, your code is doing this:

```js
fooA({
  name: window.name
})
```

and that's totally valid (although probably not what you wanted).

Comment: I think you are partially correct. Because if I change `name: string` to `innerWidth: string` I get an error saying that `string is not assignable to number`, since `window.innerWidth` is a number. But if I change to `name: number` the TS is still silent and does not complain that `window.name` should be `string`. I mean, there is something weirder in there, IMO. See the new screens I've added to the question.

Comment: Curiously enough, it seems that TypeScript types `name` as `never`, i.e. it seems to be different from `window.name` (which is `string`). [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBGC2AOEF4IDsCG0QG4BQN5IHcBLZAEwHsCA6NDHIA) This explains the lack of error, since `never` is assignable to anything.

Comment: @Cerberus Thanks. That's probably it, then. But when I do `const name = window.string`. That `name` variable is evaluated as `string`.

Comment: Yes, that' what I said too: `window.name` is `string`, but simply `name` (if it isn't defined by your code, obviously) is `never`.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution to this kind of error, ESLint can be configured to give errors when you use browser globals like `name` without an explicit reference to the window object (`window.name`)

1. Install ESLint
2. Install ESLint and it for typescript code ([instructions here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md))
3. install the `no-restricted-globals` package
4. Add this to your rules in `.eslintrc.js`:

```json
module.exports = {
  // ... other fields omitted
  rules: {
    // ... other rules omitted
    "no-restricted-globals": ["error"].concat(
      require("confusing-browser-globals")
    ),
  },
}
```